# How to add a common stylesheet repository for multiple react projects?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I want to add a common stylesheet or a repository of stylesheets which can be referred by multiple react/next.js projects. Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is you need to host the CSS file online. (Ex: GitHub) and link the file in whichever project u want.

[image]